# Count occurrence of element in list

Tags: scheme, racket

I created this method which, given a Scheme s-expression, should return the number of sub-expressions which are `equal?` to `literal` – for example `(count '((a b c) b) 'b)` should return 2.

```
(define (count list literal)
    (define (count-under list literal count)
        (cond
            [(null? list) count]
            [(member literal (car list)) (count-under (cdr list) literal (+ count 1))]))
    (count-under list literal 0))
```

I am not getting any output from what I have written so far.

Comment: I would recommend that you first solve it in a non-tail recursive way. (And `member` isn't useful - you want `(count '((b b) b) 'b)` to be 3, not two.)

Comment: Can converting '((a b c) 'b) to '(a b c b) help?

Answer (score 0):

When I try to evaluate `(count '((a b c) b) 'b)` with the definition of `count` you propose, DrRacket shows the error message

```
member: not a proper list: 'b
```

So I definitely *do* get output from what you've written so far. However, as Racket indicates, your code attempts to do a `member`-check on something that's not a list.

To see why, mentally trace what your program is doing when `list` is `'((a b c) b)` and `literal` is `'b)`:

1. Check whether `'((a b c) b)` is `null?`. It isn't, so we move to the next branch.
2. Check whether `'b` is a member of `(car '((a b c) b)`, i.e., `'(a b c)`. It is, so we execute this branch's consequent.
3. Recurse with `list` bound to `(cdr '((a b c) b)`, i.e., to `'(b)`. You correctly pass along the `literal` unchanged, and increment the `count`.
4. Check whether `'(b)` is `null?`. It isn't, so we move to the next branch.
5. Check whether `'b` is a member of `(car '(b)`, i.e., `'b`. `'b` isn't a list, so `member` throws an error.